# Template empty bracket initialization deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I think template functions can have default arguments parameters (not template parameters but runtime parameters). We can also initialize a class with an empty bracket initialization. But how does the compiler match the template ?

Why does this code compiles, how does the compiler make the deduction and what s *Args* in this function call example ?

What I have understand:
The default bracket initialization call the empty constructor, implicitly created because there is no user-defined constructor or user-defined default constructor. That is, we can initialize any pack with {}.. So the deduction don't apply there because we can't choose one pack, every pack is candidate. Maybe the default variadic template argument is <> (no arguments).

```
    template<typename...> class pack {};

    template<class... Args>
    inline auto make(pack<Args...> = {}) {

    }

    int main() { make(); }
```

(compiled with GCC)
Note: I thought it wasn't, but default argument can be useful: 2 methods of calling the function: make < int, char, int >() (normal use) or make(myPack) for packing a variadic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `make();`, the deduced `Args` is empty; `make();` has the same effect as `make<>();` in this case.

The template parameter is a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), and no template arguments are provided here. Note that function default arguments don't participate in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). Then `Args` is deduced as empty.

> If a parameter pack appears as the last P, then the type P is matched against the type A of each remaining argument of the call. Each match deduces the template arguments for the next position in the pack expansion:
>
> Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function default argument:

Comment: *`make();` has the same effect as `make<>();`* In general (not for OP's case), would `make<>()` exclude non-template `make` functions?